# How to replace \1\ with new line

Tags: text-processing, sed, replace, newlines

I have a  record like:

```
"evSchema"\1\"UAT" "evSN"\1\"uadb" "evDirsep"\1\"/" "evRootPath"\1\"/work_area/APP_UAT/" "evSchema"\1\"RMS13" "evUser"\1\"STAGE"
```

I want to replace `\1\` with new line.

I tried using `sed` for this but it’s not working.

Anyone knows how to do that??

Comment: −1 for “not working” gibberish without specifying attempts made by the poster.

Answer (score 6):

```
sed 's:\\1\\:\
:g' file
```

you will have to escape the backslashes in your match pattern. In the replacement, that's a backslash followed by a literal newline character. Some `sed` implementations, like GNU `sed` also support `\n` there as an non-standard alternative.

Output

```
"evSchema"
"UAT" "evSN"
"uadb" "evDirsep"
"/" "evRootPath"
"/work_area/APP_UAT/" "evSchema"
"RMS13" "evUser"
"STAGE"
```

Comment: Hi I used the following comment:
newevname=`echo $evname | sed 's:\\1\\:\:g'`
Here $evname stores the record and I am using newevname to store the value in a file.
the command is giving the below error:
sed: 0602-404 Function s:\1\:\:g cannot be parsed.
kindly advise how to proceed

Comment: Hi I tried using the below comment:

Comment: I assume, you are using `bash`: For assigning the output of a command to a variable, it should be: `newevname=$(echo $evname | sed ... )` , for redirecting the output to a file, use `echo $evname | sed ... > file`